# overlay text on corssfadding background

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to get text that overlays the crossfadding background. To give it a bit of context I'm using bootstrap for the first time and am trying to replicate an airbnb style website. Please let me know how I can do this. I have the html and css code below. The problem is that when I try to add text it either hides in the behind the background or goes in front and then fades away.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Connect the Javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="actions.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> BookDivide </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Starting Guide <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Starting Guide Center </li> 
                                <li><a href="#"> How It Works </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> Posting Books </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> Renting Books </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> Buying Books </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="navbar-btn"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default"> Post Your Book </a></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="home" class="panel">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="backgroundchange">
                    <div class="backgroundimg" id="back1"></div>
                    <div class="backgroundimg" id="back2"></div>
                    <div class="backgroundimg" id="back3"></div>
                    <div class="backgroundimg" id="back4"></div>
                    <div class="backgroundimg" id="back5"></div>
                    <div class="lolzies"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                    <P> © BookDivide </p>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.navbar a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Setting up the div for crossfading background */
 .panel {
    font-family:"Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 0 0;
}
.panel .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.backgroundimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#back1 {
    background: url("image/image1.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
}
#back2 {
    background: url("image/image2.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
}
#back3 {
    background: url("image/image3.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
}
#back4 {
    background: url("image/image4.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
}
#back5 {
    background: url("image/image5.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
}
@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    92% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    92% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 40s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(5) {
    animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
}
#backgroundchange div {
    animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    -webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using template of bootstrap will not full fill your requirement. Please check below links, and choose template according to your requirement.

Please Check view source of these templates and you will get idea how to do it.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

You can get all examples from here:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that bootstrap will not full full my requirement. Are you saying it is not possible to overlay text on the crossfading background?

Comment: I mean to say that the template you are using currently will not work. so you need to use jumbotron template which I mentioned in my link.

Comment: I attempted using the jumbotron class and it hid the text underneath the background.